# Grails - flash goes out of scope when forcing https

Tags: grails, spring-security, flash-scope

I'm using Spring Security Core and grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition to enforce certain areas of a website to use https. Because it works by redirecting the page from an insecure page to a secure one, it has the side effect of preventing me from using the flash scope. Is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: Put a filter in,have the redirect pass the flash message and have the filter put the message back into scope for the new session.  Or make everything https.

Comment: How do I have the filter pass the flash message or errors?

Comment: I created a filter, and flash.errors and flash.message are strangely not showing up in the "before" interceptor.

Comment: Pass the message to the filter as a parameter in the redirect.  Are you doing the redirect in a grails controller?

Comment: I'm using a grails controller, but I'm also setting flash.errors, so passing an actual object would be necessary.

Comment: No - in the redirect add a parameter error_message,  have the filter check for any incoming requests with that parameter and put that in the session as a flash.message.  When you do the redirect, you end up creating a new session - the only communication you have between these two sessions are what's in that redirect - you could create an object with session state and pass the id to that, look it up and restore - or just pass the message. Or just make everything ssl from the start - any reason you don't do that? Suddenly the entire app is more secure!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39947/discussion-between-bz-and-anonymous1)

Comment: After running into other issues, I made the whole website https. It's a reasonable solution for this website.